# Date.getUTCDay returns the wrong day

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with the Date object in JavaScript. I've tested it in Firefox and IE.

The following code shows the problem:

```
alert(new Date(Date.UTC(2011,6,5,1,0,0,0)).getUTCDay().toString());
```

I'm expecting 0 since 5 June 2011 is Sunday, but it returns 2 thinking it is Tuesday. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months start at 0, not 1.

So you're looking at July, not June. 5th July will be a Tuesday.

```
alert(new Date(Date.UTC(2011,6-1,5,1,0,0,0)).getUTCDay().toString());
// Output: 0
```

<sub>(I wrote it out like `6-1` rather than just `5` to make it clear what I've changed.)</sub>

**The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is your friend. Read it whenever you use a function**, especially if you run into trouble.